# java copy ONLY non-null modified properties value from one object to another object

Tags: java, object, properties, copy

In my Java application, copy ONLY non-null modified properties value from one object to another object.

```
Class Emp{
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private String city;
  // setter object
}
```

I have two objects

1. `"fromDb"` --> with values name="James", ***age=30*** and city=***"Mumbai"***
2. `"fromPage"` --> with values name="James", ***age=35*** and city=***`null`***

   here "fromPage" has two modified properties value - 1. age 30 to 35 and city Mumbai to null
   here I want to copy ***non-null*** values from "fromPage" to "fromDb"
   so on final "fromDb" will be name="James", ***age=35*** and city="Mumbai"

apache `BeanUtils.copyProperties` will copying all properties values.
Is there any api or better way it can be done, instead of comparing each properties.It is a jabx class, so it is huge.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `BeanUtilsBean`, you can extend the class and overwrite the method you want to change.

```
public class IgnoreNullBeanUtilsBean extends BeanUtilsBean {
  ...
  @Override
  public void copyProperties(final Object dest, final Object orig) {
    ...
    final Object value = getPropertyUtils().getSimpleProperty(orig, name);
    if (value != null) {
      copyProperty(dest, name, value);
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
 }
```

Comment: I thought this is a ugly way, maybe others library can solve it gracefully.